# Drone regulations - understanding how to figure out

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I'll preface my question by mentioning that, while this might not be the strictly on-topic, I think this community is the best that can explain the flight zones and the flight regulations.

I own a small (<250g) drone, and I am based in Europe. The drone does come with some geofencing software (DJI flysafe), but since the responsibility relies on the user, I'd like to understand more about the issue rather than blindly trust the software. The issue is made a bit more complicated since DJI's app comes with "warning" and "enhanced warning" zones, which you can simply tap "ok" - again, I'm not sure when it really is ok.

I'll mention a few areas of immediate interest for myself, but the more general is the answer, the better.

For example, around Aberdeen, UK, the fly safe app shows the airspace as

[image]

Based on my current understanding, we have a no flight zone around the airport (red), an authorization zone (blue), an enhanced warning zone (orange), a warning zone (yellow), and an altitude restriction zone (gray).

Is clear where I can't fly, where I have to ask for permission to fly, and where there is an altitude restriction. What is not clear, is how to interpret the yellow areas - apparently there is a class D airspace, which should allow for drone flights?

There is also a temporary warning over the Scottish Highlands. Where would be the best place to see if it's active?

Comment: Well, this won't help too much, but I can tell you that in the US, DJI's "geofencing" does *not* correspond well at all -- and as best I understand it, isn't even intended to-- with the no-fly and permission-required areas as established by the FAA, viewable on the LAANC map,

Comment: Hi Paul92 welcome to aviation.stackexchange.  I assume you are in the UK. I  am involved in development of the EU Concept of Operations for U-space, and related regulations for unmanned aviation. I have no detailed knowledge of the exact UK regulations, although I know they are similar to the EU regs. When it comes to airspace design and the need to obtain prior permission to fly drones in certain zones,  there are even differences between the EU member states. I will try and find out a bit more about the UK situation and post an answer if I do.

Comment: Hi @DeltaLima, thanks for the welcome. I asked the questions specifically for UK since I'm planning a trip with a newly acquired drone and doing the research for that area. I am actually based in mainland EU, so I'm actually looking for both UK and EU airspace.

Comment: "*we have a no flight zone around the airport*", interesting airport concept ;-)